# How to build an image classification dataset in Azure?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I've a set of images that have a single classification of OPEN (they show something that is open).  I couldn't find a way to directly add a status of open to the image reader dataset so I have FULL OUTER JOIN-ed a single ENTER DATA to an IMAGE READER as per the following.  This seems like a hack, does anyone know the "right" way to do this?
[image]

Comment: I am asking around.... but I couldn't come up with a "better" way to do this... My only thought is flipping the inputs and using a different join type MIGHT be better in some situations but I don't think it matters for yours... The only other option might be to use a "Execute Python Script" module and code what you want... but that doesn't sound easier to me

Comment: Are you stuck with Azure's machine learning platform? There are other ways to skin the proverbial cat...

Comment: @grill Thanks for your comment.  No I think I could solve this problem with image processing but am trying our Azure ML.

Comment: @DanCiborowski-MSFT Thanks for your comment.  I think R or Python would suit as its more intuitive than a full outer join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is to have R or python code that replicates the status for each image and then use add-columns. I think R/Python code to just replicate the status for each image may be easier and faster than outer join.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Are you able to post some skeleton (or ideally complete) R code to perform this task?

Comment: Awarded bounty for best answer, some skeleton R code would be really helpful